# Download S3 files only with VBA REST call

Tags: java, vba, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3

I see from this post ([Can you integrate Amazon S3 (or Cloud Files or Smiliar) with MS Access (VBA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760957/can-you-integrate-amazon-93-or-cloud-fileg-or-smiliar-with-ms-accegg-vba)) that, to download s3 file, we can:

- “if your content is private you'll need to create a signed url, You could create a web service on your web server to generate these signed urls"

So, it seems like I can create a rest endpoint in Java S3 client to download files with functions similar to:

```
public String downloadBase64 (String bucket, String objectName) {
  return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(IOUtils.toByteArray(client.getObject(bucket,objectName).getObjectContent()));


public String getDownloadUrl (String objectName, long expiresInMinutes){
   return get DownloadUrl (defaultBucketName, objectName, expiresInMinutes);

public String getDownloadUrl (String bucket, String objectName, long expiresInMinutes)
try{
   return client. generatePresignedUrl (bucket, objectName, DateUtil.plusHours (new Date (), 2)) . toURI(). toString () ;
} catch (Exception e) {
   throw new TechnicalException("S3 DOWNLOAD ERROR", e):
}
```

However, I have 2 questions:

1. It seem like the `downloadBase64` is the way to download the file content as string, then can we treat `getDownloadUrl` as a link which will trigger download automatically when we click it? Is it possible to download file as it is? e.g. if it's csv then we download it as csv
2. While `downloadBase64` & `getDownloadUrl` are implemented in Java, is it feasible to implement this purely from VBA? (getting the file directly from s3).  Is it even possible to get the file directly from s3 via a REST call from VBA?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This is possible, but not trivial.  You'll need an AWS Secret and Key, and recreate the logic to [sign a URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) in VBA.  [This answer might be a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74372578/aws-s3-generate-presigned-url-in-visual-basic)